# Testing a smart contract using truffle ethereum, solidity, vue.js and VScode,on localhost 8080,i get a blanck page with only name and backround color

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, visual-studio-code, localhost

i'm trying to deploy a smart contract simple application "Hello World",every thing is running successfully ..when i run : npm run serve  i get this warning :
( warning  in ./node_modules/@truffle/contract/node_modules/ethers/dist/ethers.min.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted)
and when i open localhost8080 i just get the name of my application and the background-color!..no button no text or img! i try to fix it but i didn't find the error ..there are my codes if someone can help, thnx in advance:
App.vue:

```js
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" />
        <horse></horse>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    // @ is an alias to /src
    import horse from "./components/HelloHorse.vue";

    export default {
      name: "HelloHorse",
      components: {
        horse,
      },
    };
    </script>

    <style>
    #app {
      font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-align: center;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
```

Package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ensdomains/address-encoder": "^0.2.16",
    "@truffle/contract": "^4.4.6",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "crypto-random-string": "^3.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^15.0.0",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http-browserify": "^1.7.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lint": "^0.7.0",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "serve-static": "^1.14.2",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.0-web3one.5",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "web3": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.0",
    "npm": "8.3.1"
  }
}
```

router>index.js:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HelloYouView from "../views/HelloYou.vue";
import store from "../store/index.js";
import ContractService from "../ContractService/ContractService.js";
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Hello",
    component: HelloYouView,
    beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.state.currentAccount != "") {
        next();
      } else {
        const contractService = new ContractService();
        var initweb3 = await contractService.initWeb3();
        if (!initweb3) {
          alert(
            "Install MetaMask, connect you to your account and refresh web page."
          );
          return;
        }
        var loadaccount = await contractService.loadAccount();
        if (loadaccount) {
          store.commit("setService", contractService);
          store.commit("setCurrentAccount", contractService.currentAccount);
          store.commit("setContract", contractService.contracts);
          next();
        }
      }
    },
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
export default router;
```

views< helloYou.vue:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HelloYouView from "../views/HelloYou.vue";
import store from "../store/index.js";
import ContractService from "../ContractService/ContractService.js";
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Hello",
    component: HelloYouView,
    beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.state.currentAccount != "") {
        next();
      } else {
        const contractService = new ContractService();
        var initweb3 = await contractService.initWeb3();
        if (!initweb3) {
          alert(
            "Install MetaMask, connect you to your account and refresh web page."
          );
          return;
        }
        var loadaccount = await contractService.loadAccount();
        if (loadaccount) {
          store.commit("setService", contractService);
          store.commit("setCurrentAccount", contractService.currentAccount);
          store.commit("setContract", contractService.contracts);
          next();
        }
      }
    },
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
export default router;
```

contractService.js:

```js
var Web3 = require("web3");
var TruffleContract = require("@truffle/contract");
var $ = require("jquery");
const HelloWorld = require("../../build/contracts/HelloWorld.json");
class ContractService {
  web3Provider = null;
  contracts = {};
  currentAccount = {};
  Web3 = Web3;
  TruffleContract = TruffleContract;
  $ = $;
  initWeb3 = function () {
    if (
      process.env.VUE_APP_MODE == "development" &&
      typeof window.ethereum === "undefined"
    ) {
      this.web3Provider = new this.Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        process.env.VUE_APP_LOCAL_NODE
      );
    } else if (typeof window.ethereum != "undefined") {
      this.web3Provider = this.Web3.givenProvider;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    this.Web3 = new this.Web3(this.web3Provider);
    return true;
  };
  initContract = async function () {
    var HelloWorldArtifact = HelloWorld;
    this.contracts.HelloWorld = TruffleContract(HelloWorldArtifact);
    this.contracts.HelloWorld.setProvider(this.web3Provider);
    return true;
  };
  loadAccount = async function () {
    let v_accounts;
    if (typeof window.ethereum === "undefined") {
      v_accounts = await this.Web3.eth.getAccounts();
    } else {
      v_accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    }
    this.currentAccount = v_accounts[0];
    return this.initContract();
  };
  init = async function () {
    const res = await this.initWeb3();
    if (res) {
      await this.initContract();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
}
export default ContractService;
```

this what i get :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZQEh.png)
this is the browser's console i didn't undrestund the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxCep.png)

Comment: are there any errors in the browser's console? please show them here too

Comment: this is the browser's console i didn't undrestund the error if u can help me please !.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxCep.png

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).